# ruby c extension internal structure

Tags: ruby, ruby-c-extension

[readme.ext](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/README.EXT), which is linked in ruby guides as one of the main resources to develop ruby extensions, states the following:

> Notice Ruby does not allow arbitrary pointer values to be a VALUE.
>   They should be pointers to the structures which Ruby knows about. The
>   known structures are defined in `<ruby.h>`.

So,

1. How can I hold an arbitrary structure in my object, without expose it?
2. Is there a more complete resource than the one cited on [ruby guides](http://guides.rubygems.org/c-extensions/)? While I can go in ruby C code to find the functions I need to call, it is hard to find some direct answers like for the code above on the source code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This covers all the basics, including how to use C structures with managed exposure as Ruby objects, how all the macros and functions work, and a reference to many of the functions: http://media.pragprog.com/titles/ruby3/ext_ruby.pdf

How you manage C objects associated with Ruby ones depends partly on the relationship you want to establish. You could simply create regular Ruby objects from within C, and just speed up one or two bits of complex maths for instance. Then you'd work more with `VALUE`s, at least on input to all the methods. You also get access to all of Ruby's dynamics and introspection this way, so could have an extension that worked on instance variables by finding those that were of interest in the object without knowing in advance what they were called.

However, there are macros and helper functions from `ruby.h` that help with hooking into Ruby's garbage collection for C structs and for arbitrary C data - types usually managed via `malloc`. For example the `Data_Wrap_Struct` function allows you to create an object which is effectively a C struct when you process it in your extension, but will otherwise be handled as a regular Ruby object (for assignment to variables etc). See the CD Jukebox example in the document I linked - there are several related functions you need to use to ensure your code plays correctly with Ruby's memory management.

Comment: Thanks, will look into it soon and then let you know

Comment: Is it legal to link this book here?

Comment: @fotanus: Yes, read the introduction, the PDF is released for general use, free of charge. It's an official copy.